# problema al guardar registros con fetch - error Undefined index

Tags: php, oracle

Hola tengo problemas dentro del if(isActivo($usuario))
donde quiero conseguir los valores  id, password, id_tipo, no los esta guardando y me aparece este mensaje

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\funcs\funcs.php on line 291

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\funcs\funcs.php on line 292

Notice: Undefined index: id_tipo in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\funcs\funcs.php on line 293
```

**Funcion donde esta el problema:**

```
function login($usuario, $password)
{
    global db;

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :uss OR correo = :uss");
    $stmt->bindValue(":uss",$usuario);
    $stmt->execute();
    $valor= $stmt->fetchColumn(0);

    //printf("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('El valor es : $valor'); </script>");
    if($valor > 0) 
    {
        if(isActivo($usuario))
        {
            printf("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('HOLAA'); </script>");
            $conn = $db->prepare("SELECT id, password, id_tipo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :cons OR correo = :cons");
            $conn->execute(array(":cons"=>$usuario));

            $registro = $conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $a = $registro['id'];
            $b = $registro['password'];
            $c = $registro['id_tipo'];

            $validaPassw = password_verify($password, $b); //password_verify funcion de php, Comprueba que la contraseña coincida con un hash

            printf("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Los datos son: $a, $b, $c'); </script>");

            if($validaPassw)
            {
                lastSession($id);
                $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $a;
                $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $c;

                header("location: welcome.php");

            } 
            else 
            {
                $errors = "La contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecta";
            }
            $conn->closeCursor();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $errors = 'El usuario no esta activo';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $errors = "El nombre de usuario o correo electr&oacute;nico no existe";
    }

    $stmt = null;

    return $errors;
}
```

**La conexion es:**

```
<?php
    try 
    { 
         $db = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost', 'TRABAJOFINAL','TRABAJOFINAL'); 

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        die('Error: ' .$e->GetMessage()); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué tal si no te está devolviendo datos? A tu código le faltan ciertos controles, por ejemplo, tú asumes que **siempre** devolverá datos, pero puede ser que no. ¿Si haces `var_dump($registro);` te muestra un array con las claves `id, password, id_tipo`?

Comment: @A.Cedano con el var_dump me muestra las claves, mira, me salio esto: 
1array(3) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "12" ["PASSWORD"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$8OvhYxjq1ArIwX7TvgqeqeILAatvjf58puzgEJXsDsE2ejt6Ht9U6" ["ID_TIPO"]=> string(1) "2" } pero no entiendo porque no funciona entonces..

Comment: Los nombres de clave de arrays son *case sensitive*. Dado que tus columnas están en mayúsculas, debes poner en mayúsculas los nombres de las claves cuando intentas leer sus valores: **`$a = $registro['ID'];
            $b = $registro['PASSWORD'];
            $c = $registro['ID_TIPO'];`** Otra cosa, si esperas más de una fila en los resultados de la consulta, debes abrir un bucle para leer cada fila de  resultados. Del modo como lo tienes ahora sólo te leerá la primera fila.

Comment: eres un master XD ahora me funciona perfecto :D te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: @A.Cedano si gustas pon la respuesta abajo y te doy puntos o lo que sea como funcione este foro  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si como has dicho en comentario el var_dump te devuelve esto:

```
array(3) { 
            ["ID"]=> string(2) "12" 
            ["PASSWORD"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$*****" 
            ["ID_TIPO"]=> string(1) "2" 
        }
```

debes saber que, `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` crea un array asociativo cuyas claves son los nombres de columnas de la base de datos.

El `var_dump` muestra que en tu base de datos los nombres de columnas está escritos en mayúsculas. En PHP los nombres de clave en los arrays son *case sensitive*, o sea, que `ID` y `id` no es lo mismo tratándose de una clave de array. Por tanto, debes cambiar el código así:

```
//...código

        $registro = $conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $a = $registro['ID'];
        $b = $registro['PASSWORD'];
        $c = $registro['ID_TIPO'];

//... código
```

**Nota:**

Si esperas más de una fila en los resultados de la consulta, debes abrir un bucle para leer cada fila de resultados. Del modo como lo tienes ahora sólo te leerá la primera fila.

Comment: Muchas gracias maestro. amigo de casualidad tiene algun correo, fb o algo para comunicarme con usted ?

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto:

```
$a = $registro['**ID**'];
$b = $registro['**PASSWORD**'];
$c = $registro['**ID_TIPO**'];
```

así debería funcionar.